# Prove zero slope point is global maximum for constrained function with binomials. Without restriction, objective function is non-concave

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, convex-optimization, global-optimization, binomial-distribution, non-convex-optimization

## How to prove the zero slope point is a global maximum in this non-concave program for a function with binomials?

I need to find the (global) maximum of the following constrained problem:

$$\max_{CAP} \pi[CAP] =(v-CAP) \sum_{j=1}^J j \cdot q^j (1-q)^{N-j} \binom{N}{j}  \\
+J(v-(1- \delta)C) \sum_{j=J+1}^{N} q^j (1-q)^{N-j} \binom{N}{j}  \notag \\
\text{respecting }\text{the constraint that for all }
q \in (0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}: \notag \\
0= ( CAP  - C ) \sum_{j=1}^J j N        \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-1-j}  \binom{N}{j} \\ -
\delta C \sum_{j=J+1}^{N} j N   \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{-j+N-1} \binom{N}{j}   \notag$$

Where:

endogenous variables:

- $ 0<q<1$  respects the constrained maximization
- $CAP>C$ maximizes the objective function w.r.t the constraint

exogenous variables:

- $v>0$
- $0<C<v$
- $0< \delta <1$

I have good reasons to suspect the global optimal is reached when $CAP=v$.
For the proof I write down the Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}[CAP,q,\lambda]  
=
(v-CAP) \sum_{j=1}^J j                  \cdot q^j (1-q)^{N-j} \binom{N}{j} \label{lagrangian}  \\
 +
(v- c + \delta C) \sum_{j=J+1}^{N}  J   \cdot q^j (1-q)^{N-j} \binom{N}{j}  \notag 
 +
\lambda \Bigg\{(CAP-C) \sum_{j=1}^J     q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-1-j}  \binom{N-1}{j-1}  \notag \\
 -
\delta C \sum_{j=J+1}^{N}               q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-1-j} \binom{N-1}{j-1} \Bigg\}  \notag $$

[Now I managed to show (with a very tedious, torturous proof) that $\frac{d\mathcal{L}[CAP,q,\lambda]}{d CAP}=0$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381025/how-to-prove-this-obvious-result-from-bernoulli-trials-partial-pascal-series/382098#382098), but I need to show that it is also an (global) optimum.
The problem is that the objective function $\pi[CAP]$ is not concave!
See Figure 1 and 2 for 3d representations of the objective function.
[Here is the Mathematica program](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18JtvWCrsD5S6g9uz86ZVmC4lbUS_nVM7/view?usp=sharing) I used to draw these Figures.

Fig.1:Objective Function
[image: Objective Function]
Fig.2:Objective Function - different angle
[image: Objective Function - different angle]

The constraint, however, seems concave as Figure 3 shows.
I suspect that the problem is strictly concave for all $q$ respecting the constraint, as Figure 4 indicates.

Fig.3: The constraint
[image: Constraint]

Fig.4: Intersection Objective and Constraint - 3D
[image]

Mathematica has a bit a problem to show the intersection nicely in Fig.4, so I drew some 2D graphs using simulations. E.g., see Figure 5.

Fig.5: Intersection Objective and Constraint - 2D
[image: Intersection Objective and Constraint - 2D]
The vertical line indicates the maximum. In the graph $v=200$. The plot in Fig.5 clearly shows how the maximum is attained at $CAP=200=v$ and that this is a global optimum (for the specific parameter values used to draw Fig.5).

What can I do here?
I understand that people have looked at this sort of problems.
[Heal (1984)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196885884900150) addresses non-concave objective functions in his paper " Equivalence of Saddle-Points
and Optima for Non-concave Programmes"}.
He shows that for some of these problems you can transform the variables so that the transformed problem has a concave objective problem.
That is a great idea, but I don't see what kind of transformation I could make.

Comment: Your link to the Mathematica program does not work

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by reformulating it using an economic argument.
I find it astonishing how simple the problem becomes after the reformulation/reconceptualization.
I believe there must be a form of mathematical mapping that projects the original problem onto the new problem and I am very curious what that could be.
The argument I use is economic in nature and is probably quite "chatty" for a mathematician.

## The Economic Problem

As it is key to my argument, I write the economic problem once again, adding some important details.

**The buyer**

One buyer wants to buy maximally $J$ units.
For each unit he buys, he earns $v$.
The number of units that is offered to him is $j$.
Thus, for example, with $v=10$ and  $j=3, 4, 5, 6, \text{and } 7$, the buyer earns $30, 40, 50, 50, \text{and } 50$.
The price per unit depends on the supply, but has a maximum, $CAP$, set by the buyer.

The number of units that is offered, $j$, follows a random distribution.
When the number of units $j \leq J$, the supply is less than demand, and the price per unit is as high as possible, $CAP$
When the number of units $j > J$, the price per unit is $- \delta C$, where $C$ is the fixed cost of a unit.

**The sellers**

There are $J$ identical sellers.
Each sellers has a fixed cost of $C$.
For a seller to become eligible to sell to the buyer,
it has to enter the market and I assume that this involves making a sunk investment equal to a proportion of it's cost, $\delta C$.
All sellers decides simultaneously to become eligible with probability $q$.
The probability $q$ is determined so that the sellers make zero profits in expectation.

**Variables**

Then:

- $0<q<1$   is the probability of a a unit being offered
- $v>0$     is the value of a unit for the buyer \
- $C>0$     is the fixed cost of the unit for the seller and $C<<v$  \
- $0<- \delta C<C$ is the \textit{negative} price of a unit when $j>J$.\
- $CAP>C$ is the price of a unit when $j \leq $ and a parameter to set by the buyer.

## The Original Formulation

The buyer wants to maximize its profit leads and thus originally I started out writing the Lagrangian:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}[CAP,q,\lambda] 
=&
(v-CAP) \sum_{j=1}^J j                  \cdot q^j (1-q)^{N-j} \binom{N}{j}   \\
& +
(v- c + \delta C) \sum_{j=J+1}^{N}  J   \cdot q^j (1-q)^{N-j} \binom{N}{j}  \notag \\
& +
\lambda \Bigg\{(CAP-C) \sum_{j=1}^J     q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-1-j}  \binom{N-1}{j-1}  \notag \\
& -
\delta C \sum_{j=J+1}^{N}               q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-1-j} \binom{N-1}{j-1} \Bigg\}  \notag &&
\end{align*}

However, as detailed in my post above, this approach led to a non-concave objective function and the proof that the Lagrangian has slope zero when $CAP=v$ alone is torturous,
Moreover, the proof does not establish it is a maximum, let alone a global maximum.

## Alternative (but equivalent) Formulation

The problem can be reformulated after applying some economic intuition.
The question I ask is in what precise cases the buyer's profit decreases.
There are two such cases.

**1. Over-entry**

When $j>J$ sellers decide to enter, then $j-J$ of them will not be able to sell and have made the sunk cost, $\delta C$, in vain.
I call this a case of "over-entry": Too many sellers entered the market.
The expected loss due to over-entry is thus $( \delta  C ) \sum_{j=J+1}^N (j-J)     \cdot q^{j} (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j}$.
As the sellers make zero profit by assumption, this loss is paid by the buyer and thus decreases the buyer's profit.

**2. Under-entry**

When $j<J$ sellers decide to enter, then the buyer loses out on the opportunity to buy $J-j$ items.
I call this a case of "under-entry": Too few sellers entered the market.
Each of those lost sales would have increased his profit by $(v-C)$, the value the buyer has for the item minus the cost of producing that item.
The expected loss due to under-entry is thus $( v- C ) \sum_{j=0}^J (J-j) \cdot q^{j} (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j}$.

Thus the buyer basically would like to minimize these two factors that decrease his profits.
Let's call this the loss function.
Then:

\begin{align*}
loss[q]=&( \delta  C ) \sum_{j=J+1}^N (j-J)     \cdot q^{j} (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j} \\
&+
( v- C ) \sum_{j=0}^J (J-j) \cdot q^{j} (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j}
\end{align*}

With, as in the original problem, the restriction:

\begin{align*}
&(CAP-C) \sum_{j=1}^J   q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-1-j}  \binom{N-1}{j-1}  \notag 
=
\delta C \sum_{j=J+1}^{N}               q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-1-j} \binom{N-1}{j-1}
\end{align*}

The only free parameter for the buyer is to set $CAP$.
Setting $CAP$ affects the probability of entry through the restriction $q$.
I can thus solve the problem by finding the $q$ that minimizes $loss[q]$ and use the restriction then to determine the corresponding $CAP$.

## Solving the Alternative Formulation

Let us thus differentiate $loss[q]$ and set it equal to zero.
\begin{align*}
0=&\frac{d loss[q]}{d q} \\
=& \delta  C    \sum_{j=J+1}^N  (j-J) \Big(j \cdot q^{j-1}  (1-q)^{N-j} \\
&-(N-j) \cdot q^{j} (1-q)^{N-1-j} \Big) \cdot \binom{N}{j} \\
&+
( v- C ) \sum_{j=0}^J (J-j) \Big(j \cdot q^{j-1}  (1-q)^{N-j} -(N-j)    \cdot q^{j} (1-q)^{N-1-j} \Big)             \cdot \binom{N}{j} \\
=& \delta  C  \Bigg(
    \sum_{j=J+1}^N  (j-J) j                 \cdot q^{j-1}  (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j} \\
&-
    \sum_{j=J+1}^N  (j-J) (N-j)             \cdot q^{j} (1-q)^{N-1-j}   \binom{N}{j}
    \Bigg) \\
&+
( v- C ) \Bigg( \sum_{j=0}^J (J-j) j \cdot q^{j-1}  (1-q)^{N-j}        \binom{N}{j} \\
&-
\sum_{j=0}^J (J-j) (N-j)    \cdot q^{j} (1-q)^{N-1-j}  \binom{N}{j}
\Bigg)                                                          \\
=& \delta  C  \Bigg(
\sum_{j=J+1}^N  (j-J) j                 \cdot q^{j-1}  (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j} \\
&-
\sum_{j=J+2}^{N+1}  (j-1-J) (N+1-j)             \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}   \binom{N}{j-1}
\Bigg) \\
&+
( v- C ) \Bigg( \sum_{j=0}^J (J-j) j \cdot q^{j-1}  (1-q)^{N-j}        \binom{N}{j}  \\
&-
\sum_{j=1}^{J+1} (J+1-j) (N+1-j)    \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j-1}
\Bigg)      \\
=& \delta  C  \Bigg(
\sum_{j=J+1}^N  (j-J) j                 \cdot q^{j-1}  (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j}  \\
&-
\sum_{j=J+1}^N  (j-1-J) j               \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}   \binom{N}{j}
\Bigg) \\
&+
( v- C ) \Bigg( \sum_{j=0}^J (J-j) j \cdot q^{j-1}  (1-q)^{N-j}        \binom{N}{j} \\
&-
\sum_{j=0}^J (J+1-j) j  \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j}
\Bigg)      \\
=& \delta  C  \Bigg(
\sum_{j=J+1}^N  j               \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}   \binom{N}{j}
\Bigg) \\
&- 
( v- C ) \Bigg( 
\sum_{j=0}^J  j \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j} +  J    \cdot q^{J-1} (1-q)^{N-J}  \binom{N}{J}
\Bigg)
\end{align*}

Using the restriction to substitute for the term $\delta  C  \Bigg(
\sum_{j=J+1}^N  j               \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}   \binom{N}{j}
\Bigg) $ gives:
\begin{align*}
0=& (CAP-C)  \Bigg(
\sum_{j=0}^J  j                 \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}   \binom{N}{j}
\Bigg) 
- 
( v- C ) \Bigg( 
\sum_{j=0}^J  j \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}  \binom{N}{j} 
\Bigg)          \\
=& (CAP-v)  \Bigg(
\sum_{j=0}^J  j                 \cdot q^{j-1} (1-q)^{N-j}   \binom{N}{j}
\Bigg) 
\end{align*}
We can thus conclude that $CAP \gtreqqless v \implies \frac{d loss[q]}{d q} \gtreqqless 0$ and $loss[q]$ is thus strictly convex and therefore has a global minimum at $CAP=v$.
Of course, given the setup, this implies that the buyer's profit reaches a global maximum at $CAP=v$.

Comment: I don't understand. When $M=J+1$, with your last formulation you get$$loss[q]=(v-CAP)q^M+(CAP-Mv+JC)q-J(C-v),$$for $v=CAP$ it is linear in $q$ with negative coefficient at $q$, so will attain lowest value at $q=1$. This function only has a global minimum strictly inside $(0,1)$ for $v>CAP$.